# Is “orderly existence” in this passage just a common expression?

Tags: translation

Writing to the woman who would become his third wife, Hermann Hesse complained: “Life for me now holds almost no pleasures any more, in fact I am living in Hell.” The event that had reduced Hesse to this state of near-despair was that his wife-to-be Ninon Dolbin had moved some of his books without his permission. For him this was an intolerable disruption of the **orderly existence** he believed essential to a writer who had detached himself from the world. His independence required that he hold all of humankind, and even his closest companion, at a rigorously policed distance. Accordingly, although the two of them lived under the same roof, he communicated with Ninon mainly in writing. As his latest biographer, Gunnar Decker, relates:....

My question has to do with “orderly existence” , I am going to translate this article to a different language and I am not sure if this really means simply organized life for any person or it is a technical philosophical expression?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the phrase **orderly existence** is a common expression.  Here it could be replaced with the noun **orderliness**.   The implication is of a rigorous, unbending, quasi-monastic observance of order, there being a designated place, time, and manner for everything.